# Why can't I access files / directories outside of wordpress

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I am trying to add files to the root of my wordpress directory (my www folder) but can't access them on my site.

For instance,  I have a directory called resources and I put that in my www folder.  I can't access any of the files in there.  Whenever I do it just shows a file not found error on the site.

I tried putting an info.php (with php_info()) in it.  BUt that gives me the same error (404) when i try to access on the frontend by going to www.example.com/info.php.

I know I used to be able to do this!

I deleted everything in my www directory except the resources directory and the info.php.

When I try to access them after that I get this error:

> Internal Server Error  500
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@rudtek.com to
>   inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I tried uploading this [SRDB](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) program to change the home directory to see but I can't even access that script.  (yes when i installed this program, i put the wp-config.php back...still no luck)

Comment: in that same folder its your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: "I deleted everything in my www directory except the resources directory and the info.php." - including the `index.php` and `.htaccess` files?

Comment: yes.  I deleted everything.  Just tried adding .htaccess back.  no change.

Comment: Have you check the file permissions? If you've deleted `index.php` and `.htaccess` then you've effectively deleted WordPress (at least WordPress cannot process anything), so this would seem to be a server config issue?

Comment: thats my thought... but can't imagine what setting would do that.  any ideas?

Comment: Does (or did) WordPress itself work? (I assume it did?) If WordPress worked, then it further suggests a permissions (or file ownership) problem? Have you checked this?

Comment: yes.  all files were deleted.  so weird.